# Find number of Ratings requested and provided per day

Tags: sql, data-analysis

I have the following columns

```
date  |  id  |  score  |
```

`score` has options like `offered`, `good`, and `bad`.

How to write a query that gives the number of ratings offered vs. the number of queries provided (score is either `good` or `bad`) per day.

Comment: Start an SQL question by showing the schema for all the relevant tables. Do a `SHOW CREATE TABLE YourTableName;` for each table, and paste it into the questions as text (NOT A PICTURE). 
An example of the data contained in these tables is also very useful. 
If at all possible create a SQLFiddle with the schema defined and some test data provided.

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
   SUM(
       CASE 
           WHEN score IN ('good', 'bad') THEN 1
           ELSE 0
       END
   ) AS good_or_bad
   SUM(
       CASE
           WHEN score = 'offered' THEN 1
           ELSE 0
       END
   ) AS offered
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY date
```

In the above, I'm using `case-when` to determine the `score`. The first field is for `good_or_bad`, so I'm counting the elements where the score is either good or bad. The second is for `offered`, so I'm counting the records whose `score` is offered. Since you want to `group by` `date`, that's added as well

**NOTE**

`date` might be a `varchar`, a `date` or a `timestamp`. In my query above I assumed that `date` is of day precision. If it's like a `timestamp`, then you will need to modify the `group by` to extract the actual date.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entire clear what output you want from this, but I think you are looking for something like the following?

```
SELECT t1.date, t1.all, t2.offered
FROM (SELECT date_trunc('day', date) "date", count(*) "all"
  FROM test
  GROUP BY 1) t1
JOIN (SELECT date_trunc('day', date) "date", count(*) "offered"
  FROM test
  WHERE score = 'offered'
  GROUP BY 1) t2
ON t1.date = t2.date;
```

This will group by the date, and output the total rows per date, and total rows with a "score" of 'offered' per date. [Here's a fiddle of this running](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4jyoMCicNSZpjMt4jFYoz5/4312)

Comment: The question asks for offered vs. good-or-bad, your answer provides all vs offered. It is true that all - offered would yield that value, but the problem with this approach is that you assume that either now **or in the future** there will be no fourth value and that the field is not nullable. Also, creating subqueries and joining them is not very performant. Kindly look into my answer which achieves the result with a single query, without subqueries or joins.

Comment: @LajosArpad What the OP wanted is, at this point, a matter of interpretation to be fair. The OP says "the number of ratings offered vs. the number of queries provided", which I took to mean the number "offered" vs the total number. Your solution makes similar assumptions, like the values in "score" being ONLY 'good', 'bad', or 'offered', which is why I didn't use a your approach, as mine is potentially more scalable in this regard.

Comment: First of all, the asker said that "How to write a query that gives the number of ratings offered vs. the number of queries provided (score is either good or bad) per day.". So he/she needs the number of ratings offered as the first field of the result set and the queries provided (either good or bad) as the second field.

Comment: Secondly "Your solution makes similar assumptions, like the values in "score" being ONLY 'good', 'bad', or 'offered', which is why I didn't use a your approach, as mine is potentially more scalable in this regard.". The questions specify these as the possible values, so even if one assumed that, it would not be baseless. However, it is not necessary to assume it, as the asker asks for the total number of offered (specified as having a score of offered) vs. the total number of queries provided (specified as either good or bad).

Comment: My answer did not assume that there is no fourth possible value, a `foo` for example. Instead, my answer makes sure to compute a query that takes into account only the values that the asker is interested about. So, if there is a `foo` value that differs from the three, then it will not be computed into either sums, as the op clearly specified the three values he/she is interested about and `foo` is not among them, even if it exists as a value. Computing all records would mix a `foo` into the "all" result - if such a value exists - and the asker has shown no interest in it.

Comment: The logical error is that, if a `foo` value exists and it is computed into the all as per your solution, then all - offered would have n + k, where n is the number of good or bad and k is the number which differs from good, bad or offer.

Comment: So, computing all - offered will necessarily consider any `null` or `foo` values for `score` to be either good or bad. While my answer will only consider good/bad values to be the ones which actually have those values, it will also count the offered values and ignore anything else. So, the problems which prevent me from upvoting your answer are as follows: 1. you unnecessarily create two subqueries, whereas you could compute the all based on my solution, by replacing the first field with `count(1)`.

Comment: 2. You compute any values, such as `null` into the all, so if the asker calculates all-offered, he/she will be potentially misled by the result, thinking that it represents only good or bad values. If there are indeed only those three values and it will remain unchanged and the field is not nullable, then this is not a problem. But if there are other values or even the potential for other values, then this answer is incorrect.

Comment: 3. You load the table twice fully, which will waste a lot of resources in terms of memory and time if the table is big, especially since you have a group by criteria of a calculation which is probably not indexed and then join those. You could simplify your query to be equivalent with yours without a subquery and having a single aggregation without joins.

Comment: @LajosArpad Once again, all of the above is full of assumptions and interpretations that the OP is yet to clarify. It could be that the only options for that column are "good, bad and offered", it could be that `foo` values and nulls shouldn't be included and it could be that this table is massive and efficiency is important. Or none of the above could be true. We don't know yet. I offered a solution which solved the problem, and it does that. If you don't want to upvote, that's fine, but unless the OP clarifies further, your answer is just an alternative based on different assumptions.

Comment: A better performance is obviously better than a worse performance. While it is true that one should avoid to optimize prematurely, but that is mainly valid on existent code that works. It is also valid when one writes code in terms of avoiding over-complication. However, your less performant code is unnecessarily complicating the problem, so simplifying it is not premature. It requires less effort to understand and write a simpler code and in this case the simpler code is performing better.

Comment: You seem to think that counting only 'good' and 'bad' as good or bad is an assumption. However, that was specified as the intention as "the number of queries provided (score is either good or bad)". So, counting everything that differs from 'offered' is just assuming that it is correct to add values to that count even if they are null or a fourth value. So it is you who assume things here. Your code assumes that null|foo either doesn't exist or is equivalent to good or bad. My code does not assume that. My code counts items exactly as the asker specified.

Comment: Also, your code clearly contradicts the requirements, as the question asks for good/bad vs offered. Counting all vs. offered is clearly different. But I'm done discussing your solution, as you clearly do not intend to improve it.

Comment: @LajosArpad No you're right I don't, because you've said nothing to merit an improvement at this point. If the OP clarifies further and it becomes clear your solution is better then fair enough, but that's not the case. I suppose the lesson here is don't take people to task on their answers when you don't have all the facts.